# Expected value of type Entity for association field got Entity1 instead when using ResolveTargetEntityListener

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am using the ResolveTargetEntityListener from Doctrine to access SQL tables that are in an external database.

when I use the createQueryBuilder to query the data on the external/base Vehicle class I get the following error:

`Expected value of type "AppBundle\Entity\VehicleFox" for association field "AppBundle\Entity\FM_Positions#$truck", got "FoxBundle\Entity\Vehicle" instead.`

When I do it on the internal VehicleFox class the Query returns NULL.

Is there anything that I have missed?

Below is the Controller which I am doing the query from withe the relevant functions. I have also included the classes and interfaces that have been used as well as the config.yml file.

FmController

```
<?php

namespace BWT\FMBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\DateType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Vendors\FM;
use AppBundle\Entity\FuelData;
use MaxBundle\Entity\UdoDriver;
use FoxBundle\Entity\Vehicle;
use AppBundle\Entity\FM_Positions;

class FMController extends Controller
{
    public function latestPositionsAction(Request $request)
    {
        $_render_args = array();
        $_results = array();
        $tripProcesses = new FM();
        $success = $this->login($tripProcesses);

        If ($success === true) {
            $_results = $tripProcesses->getTrackingData();
        }
        if ($_results) {
            $_render_args['results'] = $_results;
        }
        $this->CreateFmPositions($_results);
        return $this->render('Telematics/latestPositions.html.twig', $_render_args);
    }

    private function CreateFmPositions(array $results)
    {
        foreach ($results as $result){

            $resultArray = (array) $result;
            $vehicle = $this->getVehicleFM($resultArray['VehicleID']);
            $position = new FM_Positions();
            if ($vehicle) {
                $position->setTruck($vehicle[0]);
            }
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($position);
            $em->flush();
        }
    }

    private function getVehicleFM(int $vehFmId)
    {
        $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('FoxBundle:Vehicle', 'foxem'); // error for incorrect Entity
        //$repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:VehicleFox'); // returns NULL
        $query = $repository->createQueryBuilder('v')
        ->where('v.fmId = :fmid')
        ->setParameter('fmid', $vehFmId)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();

        return $query;
    }
}
```

Fm_Positions.php

```
<?php
// src/AppBundle/Entity/FM_Possitions.php
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use AppBundle\Model\VehicleInterface;
use AppBundle\Model\UDODriverInterface;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="fm_positions")
 * @author sarah
 *
 */

class FM_Positions
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Model\VehicleInterface", inversedBy="fm_positions")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="truck_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     * @var VehicleInterface
     */
    private $truck;
    // ...
}
```

Base Vehicle class

```
<?php
namespace FoxBundle\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
/**
 * Vehicle
 * @ORM\Table(name="vehicle", uniqueConstraints={@ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="fleet_number", columns={"fleet_number"})}, indexes={@ORM\Index(name="log_book_date", columns={"log_book_date"})})
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Vehicle
{
    /**
     * @var string|null
     * @ORM\Column(name="fleet_number", type="string", length=20, nullable=true)
     */
    private $fleetNumber;

    /**
     * @var string|null
     * @ORM\Column(name="FM_ID", type="string", length=20, nullable=true)
     */
    private $fmId;

    // ...
}
```

Extended Vehicle Class

```
<?php
// src/AppBundle/Entity/VehicleFox.php
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use FoxBundle\Entity\Vehicle as BaseVehicle;
use AppBundle\Model\VehicleInterface;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="vehicle_fox")
 */
class VehicleFox extends BaseVehicle implements VehicleInterface
{

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string|null
     * @ORM\Column(name="fleet_number", type="string", length=20, nullable=true)
     */
    private $fleetNumber;

    /**
     * @var string|null
     * @ORM\Column(name="FM_ID", type="string", length=20, nullable=true)
     */
    private $fmId;

     /**
      * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="FM_Positions", mappedBy="truck")
      */
    private $fm_positions;
}
```

Vehicle Interface

```
<?php
// src/AppBundle/Model/VehicleInterface.php

namespace AppBundle\Model;

interface VehicleInterface
{

    public function __construct();
    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getId();
    public function addTruckUnit(\AppBundle\Entity\Truck_Units $truckUnit);
    public function removeTruckUnit(\AppBundle\Entity\Truck_Units $truckUnit);
    public function getTruckUnits();
    public function addFmPosition(\AppBundle\Entity\FM_Positions $fmPosition);
    public function removeFmPosition(\AppBundle\Entity\FM_Positions $fmPosition);
    public function getFmPositions();
    public function addFmTrip(\AppBundle\Entity\FM_Trips $fmTrip);
    public function removeFmTrip(\AppBundle\Entity\FM_Trips $fmTrip);
    public function getFmTrips();
    public function addSkytrackPosition(\AppBundle\Entity\Skytrack_Positions $skytrackPosition);
    public function removeSkytrackPosition(\AppBundle\Entity\Skytrack_Positions $skytrackPosition);
    public function getSkytrackPositions();

}
```

Config.yml

```
doctrine:
  # ...
  orm:
    resolve_target_entities:
        AppBundle\Model\VehicleInterface: AppBundle\Entity\VehicleFox
    auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
    default_entity_manager: maxem
    entity_managers:
        maxem:
            connection: maxdb
            mappings:
                AppBundle: 
        foxem:
            connection: foxdb
            mappings:
                FoxBundle: ~
```

FMPositionType form

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class FM_PositionsType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('position_id')
            ->add('truck_id', EntityType::class, Array(
                'class' => 'FoxBundle:Vehicle',
                'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er){
                    return $er->createQueryBuilder('v')
                    ->orderBy('v.fleetNumber', 'ASC');
                },
                'placeholder' => 'Select A Truck',
                'choice_label' => 'fleetNumber',
                'em' => 'foxem',
                ))
            ->add('driver_id', EntityType::class, Array(
                'class' => 'MaxBundle:UdoDriver',
                'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er){
                    return $er->createQueryBuilder('d')
                    ->orderBy('d.nickname', 'ASC');
                },
                'placeholder' => 'Select A Driver',
                'choice_label' => 'nickname',
                'em' => 'max2em',
                ))
            ->add('date')
            ->add('latitude')
            ->add('longitude')
            ->add('heading')
            ->add('speed')
            ->add('altitude');
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\FM_Positions'
        ));
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return 'appbundle_fm_positions';
    }


}
```

Comment: If i do understand, you're trying to create new FM_Position entities but when try to select a vehicule and associate it with the position you either have an exception or a null result

Comment: yes that is correct @OlivierC

Comment: Did you try to precise the entityManager to use since you have no default $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:VehicleFox', 'maxem');

Comment: I have set `default_entity_manager: maxem` and have also tried `$repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:VehicleFox', 'maxem'); ` and I'm still getting a NULL result

Comment: I guess the results array comes from a form, can you provide both code for the form and the action where you build it

Comment: @OlivierC the result array actually comes from an API call which is returning the correct data with a valid 'VehicleID'. Everyting works fine until the `$this->getDoctrine()->getRepository()` call.

Comment: The Null or exception error occurs when `$em->flush()` is called and it it complaining about the result from the query in `getVehicleFM(int $vehFmId)`.

Comment: I got that. What I think is you tried to set a solution to create new positions and your solution is not working, and maybe we can work together on a better way to create those new positions. So can you share the code of your form and the method where it is created

Comment: @OlivierC please see my edit to the FMController and the new FMPosition Types form

Comment: the action is the latestPositionsAction.